# Where do I store custom data in an Event item so attendees can also fetch that custom data?

Tags: ms-office, office-js, exchangewebservices, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

What properties can/should we use to store custom json data in an event item?
We're currently trying to develop a web add-in, which has a form that should be sent as json within a property of the Event item, so whenever another person (i.e. an attendee) opens the add-in, the same form will show for them.

In a VSTO C# add-in, we can set an Outlook.UserProperty for this, which seems to propagate to attendees whenever the organizer edits the value.

In javascript, I've tried the following:

1. Setting a CustomProperties value, by fetching the values with `Office.context.mailbox.item.loadCustomPropertiesAsync` and setting the value via `properties.set(FORM_KEY, JSON.stringify(jsonObject)); properties.saveAsync(...);`.
2. Creating a SingleValueExtendedProperty like so:

```
fetch(Office.context.mailbox.restUrl+"/v2.0/me/events('"+getRestId(itemId)+"')", {
    method: "PATCH",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        SingleValueExtendedProperties: [
            { 
              PropertyId: singleValueExtendedPropertyId,
              Value: JSON.stringify(jsonObject)
            }
        ]
    })
})
```

3. Creating a data extension like so:

```
fetch(Office.context.mailbox.restUrl+"/v2.0/me/events('"+getRestId(itemId)+"')/extensions('Microsoft.OutlookServices.OpenTypeExtension."+extensionName+"')", 
{ 
    method: "PATCH",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken
    },
    body: 
        JSON.stringify({
            "@odata.type": "Microsoft.OutlookServices.OpenTypeExtension",
            ExtensionName: extensionName,
            Value: JSON.stringify(jsonObject)
        })
})
```

These all work **for the organizer**...
They are never propagated to the attendees.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, storing custom data on events/meetings that is accessible to both the attendees and organizer is not supported. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user-voice page](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins). Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered, when we go through our planning process.